# linq to entities

Tags: entity-framework

I have two three tables named
**Language,Language  Type,Employee**

Fields of Language Type are **LId,LanguageType**

Fields Of Language are **LId,EmpId,Language fluency**

Fields of Employee are **EmpId ,EmpName**

Relationship between Language Type and language is **one –to-one**, and language and Employee table is **many -to –one**. Problem is when I enter data in language it displays the error

```
A dependent property in a Referential Constraint is mapped 
to a store-generated column. Column: 'LId'."}.
```

Even though data is being inserted in language Type but not in language table .
lINQ query is  for language table is

```
public void AddEmpLanguage(Language language, long id)   
{ 
   using (var context = new HRMSEntities())
  {
       Language emp = new Language
       {
            EmpId = id,
            LanguageFluency = language.LanguageFluency,
        };
       context.Language.AddObject(emp);
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear here, what is the actual problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the language directly to a employee object

```
public void AddEmpLanguage(Language language, long empId)   
{ 
    using (var context = new HRMSEntities())
    {
        Language lang = new Language
        {
            LanguageFluency = language.LanguageFluency,
        };
        var employee = context.Employees.Find(empId);
        /*          or context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == empId); */
        if(employee != null){
            employee.Languages.Add(lang);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```